# How to make the height of a column 100%

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I use materialcss and using its caousel. Inside carousel I have added a row and two columns which have different content.But the problem is the height of columns are not full. Look at this screenshot

[image]

The green and the blue columns should be of full height as of its parent div (the red) one.

I applied `height:100%` but still it didn't affect. Can anyone help me out?

This is the output when it is resized

[image]

I have added css and html please help me out

```css
.full-height {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.reach-content {
  background-color: #00695c;
}

.center-horizontal {
  text-align: center;
}

.center-vertical {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #00695c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
  <div class="carousel-item red" href="#one!">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m8 blue full-height">
        <h2>First Panel First firstFirst First</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col m4 reach-content white-text">
        <h1>20</h1>
        <h5 class="white-text">Projects</h5>
        <p class="white-text">Successfully completed and delivered</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
    <h2>Second Panel</h2>
    <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
    <h2>Third Panel</h2>
    <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
    <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
    <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `height:100vh;` instead of `height:100%;`

Comment: What is this vh?

Comment: Length units representing 1% of the viewport size for viewport width height (vh).  I have never had any success setting heights by percentages.

also, I was unable to render the code you have pasted so I can't see what you are working with, but I also suspect that on of your divs higher in your DOM hierarchy needs to also have '.full-height' applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this issue by adding this into your style sheet:

```
.col{min-height: 1000px !important;}
```

It replaces the default 1px min height in the materialize css.